# How to intercept a message: "WM_QUIT || WM_DESTROY || WM_CLOSE" WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

I use this code for the main loop (my function):

```
    while (running)
{
    if(is_close)
    {
        Log().push_log("close", "message close!", logInfo);
        running = active = false;

        break;
    }

    while (PeekMessage(&msg, g_hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        std::cout << "Wnd: " << msg.message << std::endl;

        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT || msg.message == WM_DESTROY || msg.message == WM_CLOSE)
        {
            MessageBox(0, "Hello, World", "Hello", MB_OK);
            running = false;
        }
        // TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    if (running && active)
        render.DrawObject(g_hDC);
}
```

Well, then I use WndProc:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK GLWindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::cout << "Wnd Proc: " << msg << std::endl;

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

When I'm trying to get the message `WM_QUIT`, `WM_DESTROY`, or `WM_CLOSE` in my function, it does not work. My function does not see messages.

How can I get this message?

Comment: You are applying a filter (`g_hWnd`) in your call to `PeekMessage`. Unless you have very specific needs to do so, don't filter messages. Pass `NULL` instead.

Comment: You will have provide specific information. What is *"my function"*? What does *"it does not work"* mean? Do you get an error? A different result from what you expected? What did you expect?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

PeekMessage or GetMessage will only return messages that were posted to the message queue with PostMessage().  That will never be WM_CLOSE or WM_DESTROY, those messages are sent with SendMessage(), directly delivered to the window procedure and don't go in the message queue.  You won't get WM_QUIT unless you've got a PostQuitMessage() call in your code, you don't.

You really do have to write a window procedure for your main window.  Simply handling WM_DESTROY and calling PostQuitMessage(0) should be enough.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK GLWindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (msg == WM_DESTROY) PostQuitMessage(0);
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

You'll now get WM_QUIT in your game loop.